# Send Exact Target email with attachment FuelSDK

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, fuel-sdk, c#

I have a c# task which is using Fuel SDK to create and send a simple email. How do I attach a file to that email with tracking enabled when somebody opens the attachment.

Answer (score 1):

Attachments are handled using the AttachFile() AMPScript function which would need to be included in the email content.

More info: http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/email_attachments/

Tracking is not available for attachments.  A better option may be to upload your file to your Marketing Cloud Portfolio, then provide a link to the document in the email so that way it can be tracked.